# How do I get a webpage to programmatically load content the way it does when I manually scroll down?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape some news links from [this](https://www.philstar.com/business) website. For that, my code is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base = "https://www.philstar.com/business/"
page = requests.get(base)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

li_box = soup.find_all("href")

links = open("News article links.txt", "w+")

for a in li_box:
    links.write(base+a['href']+"\n")
```

The problem is, it only finds about 15-16 links displayed on the landing page. If you manually scroll down to the bottom of the page, you can see that it loads up more news content. Scroll more, and it will load more, and so on. The code cannot perform this "scroll down to see more" part. How do I scrape all those news (or, say, the first 1000)?

Comment: If you want to stick to `requests` and still get all the  data from that webpage then [try manipulating this link according to the query](https://www.philstar.com/lazy_section.php?page=1&sid=27&pubid=1&last=1828435&last_date=1530115200&last_trend=75&exceed=).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html) for this. I have modified your code little bit it will give you idea how to do it.

**Try This:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome('--path--')      # here path of driver if it didn't find it.

base = "https://www.philstar.com/business/"

browser.get(base)

''' to auto scroll page '''
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

html_source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")


li_box = soup.find_all('a')     # here whatever you want to find
print(li_box)
```

Hope this will help you! :)
Thankyou!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about selenium before, until the first answerer wrote about it. I was just looking into how to get started with it, your code definitely would help me fast track the process, so thanks again! By the way, how did you know I was using the chrome driver? I ask because when I checked selenium's documentation, most of the time, they deafult to using the firefox browser. So, was it a coincidence that your code uses the chrome browser? Just curious :)

Comment: That's good. My pleasure! :) and i don't know that you are using chrome its just a coincidence because i also used chrome not firefox :)

Answer (score 0):

For this case I would probably consider using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html).

With Selenium you can use a page scroll method that will allow you to simulate the user behaviour of scrolling through a webpage. For some guidance see the following:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html#how-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-page
http://blog.varunin.com/2011/08/scrolling-on-pages-using-selenium.html